# Facebook access token for page

Tags: php, facebook, access-token, facebook-access-token

My problems is how can I make access token from SDK 5 or manualy? When I generate it from explorer Grapth tools its works. But its exprires after 60 days. I want generate ir for every page load or something like what. I just want get page: new_like_count...

Here is my code using SDK 5:

```
// FACEBOOK PAGE LIKES
    $fb = new Facebook([
        'app_id' => config('facebook.app.id'),
        'app_secret' => config('facebook.app.secret'),
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5'
    ]);

    $app = new FacebookApp(
        config('facebook.app.id'),
        config('facebook.app.secret')
    );

    $request = new FacebookRequest(
        $app,
        config('facebook.access_token'),
        'GET',
        '/me/?fields=new_like_count'
    );

    $response = $fb->getClient()->sendRequest($request);

    //dd($response);
    $view['facebook_likes'] = $response->getGraphNode()['new_like_count'];
```

P.S. I'm new at this. So i need some help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works:

```
// FACEBOOK PAGE LIKES
    $fb = new Facebook([
        'app_id' => config('facebook.app.id'),
        'app_secret' => config('facebook.app.secret'),
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5'
    ]);

    $response = $fb->get(
        config('facebook.page.id').'/?fields=likes',
        $fb->getApp()->getAccessToken()->getValue()
    );

    $view['facebook_likes'] = $response->getGraphNode()['likes'];
```

Only thing i change is from:

```
config('facebook.page.id').'/?fields=new_like_count',
```

to

```
config('facebook.page.id').'/?fields=likes',
```

I realized: access page protected content is available when user is logged in and has permissions.

Comment: better edit your question if you changed something, don´t create an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can get facebook access token by using `getAccessToken()` method of facebook SDK.

```
$pageId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; // put your page id here
$page_info = $fb->api("/$pageId?fields=access_token"); // page info in array
echo 'access token : '. $page_info['access_token']; // get access token from array
```

Or

```
echo 'access token : '. $access_token = $fb->getAccessToken(); // get access token directly
```

Comment: But in my SDK do not exists method. It saying: Call to undefined method Facebook\Facebook::getAccessToken()

Comment: same.. now it looks:

// FACEBOOK PAGE LIKES
        $fb = new Facebook([
            'app_id' => config('facebook.app.id'),
            'app_secret' => config('facebook.app.secret'),
            'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5'
        ]);
  
  $fb->getApp();
  
        $request = new FacebookRequest(
   $fb->getApp(),
            config('facebook.access_token'),
            'GET',
            '/me/?fields=new_like_count'
        );

        $response = $fb->getClient()->sendRequest($request);

  //dd($response);
        $view['facebook_likes'] = $response->getGraphNode()['new_like_count'];

Comment: where is my code you have added?
$pageId = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; 

$page_info = $fb->api("/$pageId?fields=access_token"); // page info in array
echo 'access token : '. $page_info['access_token'];

Comment: is there any base_facebook.php file in your sdk?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102238/discussion-between-amit-rajput-and-ernestyno).

Comment: Thanks for help. I got it.